# "Backups" (deja-dup): after installing duplicity 0.8 from source, "Backups" can't find it

Tags: backup, path, restore, duplicity, dejadup

When using "Backups" (a.k.a. deja-dup) - it doesn't find duplicity, although it's installed:

I have been trying to backup using "Backups" (a.k.a. deja-dup), and it turns out that the current duplicity (which deja-dup uses) still has the "Unicode bug" (it fails when dealing with Unicode strings).
(I have "Backups" (a.k.a. deja-dup) installed on my system: "deja-dup backup tool" v 37.0, and had duplicity v 0.7.17).

My system:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
Description:   Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS; Release:  18.04; Codename:   bionic
```

So, I then removed the existing installation of duplicity, and installed duplicity 0.8 from source: https://launchpad.net/duplicity. It installs duplicity at: /usr/local/bin. It's in PATH:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

After loading and installing all the requirements, duplicity 0.8 itself runs fine:

```
~$ duplicity -V
duplicity 0.8.05
```

But, when running "Backups" (deja-dup), it doesn't find it. A window pops up, saying:

> INSTALL PACKAGES
>
> In order to continue, the following package needs to
>   be installed: duplicity

I installed dconf-editor, found /org/gnome/deja-dup, but I don't see there any settings for the duplicity path.

nautilus and "apt list --installed" don't see it, either.

Note: cross posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179953)

Comment: Cross posting is discouraged on the SE network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Where does `deja-dup` search for `duplicity`? AFAIK the standard installation path is `/usr/bin/duplicity`, so set a symlink there. I assume `deja-dup` uses absolute paths for commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deja-dup does not look for the duplicity binaries but looks at the installed packages.

Try to recompile deja-dup without HAS-PACKAGEKIT defines. This can be done by commenting out these lines in meson.build

```
#if packagekit_dep.found()
#common_vflags += ['--define=HAS_PACKAGEKIT']
#endif
```